# React Native and Redux Propert 'products' does not exist on type 'Default Reducer'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, mobile, react-redux

It says it doesn't exist , and I saw some ways to fix it but it was for people who used TypeScript something that I'm not using in this app.

Here is app js and the screen where the problem appears.

[image: App]

[image: Screen]

Comment: Stackoverflow's community can't help you if you don't provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), try to edit your question and take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.